# User Management in same or multiple table

Tags: database

Please suggest your views on the following problem.

We have an app, which consists of an Admin Panel, Web Services and Front End for users.

So, we are designing a DB for User management.

Front end users will login (using Username and Password ) and on successfull login we will have following values in session
- display_name
- email

Web Service users will login using ( Username + api_key or auth_hash ) and no session will be created

Front End / Web Service Users can add there details like:
First Name
Last Name
Phone
Profile Pic ... many more

What can be the perfect database design for this

1) One Table for storing all the info like:

id username password auth_key/hash display_name email first_name last_name phone profile_pic etc..

Problems :
- For login functionality we have extra columns in the table.
- For getting details again we have extra columns in the table.

2) Two tables

user_login

id username password auth_key display_name email

user_details

first_name last_name phone profile_pic

Problems:

Some columns like email and name required for both login functioanlity and showing details.
if we keep them in one table we need to add a JOIN while fetching, which we should avoid.
if we keep email in both table then it is a security issue.

Please suggest the best way. Or some other way of acheiving this.

--
Thanks

Comment: Why do you "should avoid join"?

Comment: Your question answer it all. Thanks